# How to filter postgresql query by date using python

Tags: python, postgresql

In my postgres, I have a field **created_at** and **updated_at**. I'm using python to query the database using cursor. The problem is, when I pass a date in python string in order to filter by **created_at** column, I get an error

> TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

When i cast the two fields into **varchar()**, I'm able to get the results.
How can I still get the same result without casting the two fields?

query

```
SELECT
    id,
    CAST(created_at AS varchar(40)),
    CAST(updated_at AS varchar(40)),
    amount
FROM
    public.table_1
WHERE created_at >= (%s) and created_at <= (%s);
```

python

```
def read_latest_data_from_pg(**kwargs):
    with open('dags/scripts/sql_scripts/pg_export_sql/sql_file.sql','r') as sqlfile:
            pg_export_data_query=str(sqlfile.read())
    max_1 = '2021-05-01'
    max_2=  '2021-05-28'
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='pg_conn', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = pg_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(pg_export_data_query, (max_1 , max_2))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('result', result)
    return result, len(result)
```

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward. At some point you are converting the result into JSON and the Python `json` module does not deal with `datetime` unless you provide a `default`.  Best guess it is either in `pg_export_data_query` or in whatever `PostgresHook is? You will need to update your question to provide more information on both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns created_at & updated_at are either 'date' or 'timestamp without timezone' in postgresql, you need to just tweak your sql, so no need of casting it, with passing inputs in datetime format.

*Note: I have used psycopg2 directly to get this query working.*

```py
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    cur = con.cursor()

    today = datetime.date.today()
    first = today.replace(day=1)

    # last day of month
    max1 = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    # first day of month
    max2 = max1.replace(day=1)

    sql = "SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, amount FROM public.table_2 WHERE created_at >= %s::date and created_at <= %s::date"
    
    cur.execute(sql, (max2, max1))

    result = cur.fetchall()

    return JsonResponse({ 'result': result } , safe=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Two problems with this answer: 1) You should not be using `f` string formatting. See here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for why. 2) The error has nothing to do with the `CAST`, it is occurring because in an as yet unrevealed portion of the code the data is being transformed to `JSON`  and the `json` module can't deal with a `datetime` unless you provide code to do so.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I have changed the answer accordingly. Also updated the response which I missed to add.

Comment: Except the OP is not using Django.

Comment: You are killing it Adrian. Is there a follow button on SO profile ;-)